# SVG renders different in browser vs in ubuntu/gimp

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've been working on a graphing application using `d3.js` and using the `svg` based renderer to produce the graph seen below. This is a screen shot of how the graph appears in both FireFox 29 and Chrome 34 on 64bit Ubuntu. Notice here that the graph has faint grey grid lines along the ticks and there are distinct black lines along the axis. [image: Correct Browser Render]

One feature that I want is the ability to download the svg to disk, and since it is just in svg format, I took everything from the svg and dumped it with the right mimetype to a file. The issue is not a single grid line appears on the desktop when viewed in the Ubuntu image viewer, GIMP 2.8, or even the default imagemagick viewer. Each of these look the same as the picture below [image: Incorrect rendering in Desktop viewers]

My issue is that, while the graphs online are very important, it is also important that the graph is viewable from the desktop as well. The only desktop software that rendered the gridlines on my computer was Inkscape, but I don't want to have to ask all the people that want to view it to use inkscape. My idea is to find a better way to render those lines that will work cross platform between the desktop and the browser.

The relevant `d3.js` code is

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis.ticks(10)
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    ).append("text")
        .attr("dx", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .text("Hours");
svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis.ticks(10)
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    ).append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Cores");
```

and the css for the axis lines is as follows. (This css is inlined into the actual svg and I have already checked to make sure that all the related css to the svg was inline. There is no css affecting the browser version of the graph that is not also included in the inline svg)

```
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightgrey;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

And the last thing is the svg [uploaded to a github gist](https://gist.github.com/jroweboy/9cb411c8248a9cecd8dc). In summary, I want to change the gridlines so that they are properly rendered on the desktop as well, but one, I don't know why they are not rendering correctly on the desktop, and two, I don't know an appropriate work around to draw gridlines that work on Desktop as well.

Comment: Are you doing any downscaling when you are converting with GIMP/ImageMagick?  If you make the stroke-widths thicker do they render then?

Comment: Have you tried setting the CSS properties directly (i.e. with D3) instead of having the CSS file?

Comment: Gimp/Imagemagick don't know CSS. So you have to style graph explicitly. Or use Inkscape.